# How to scan for and remove (or recover) corrupted Word documents in a folder?

Tags: microsoft-word, data-recovery, file-corruption

I have an old dying hard drive which I could not recover files from using TestDisk, so I instead used [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) to scan the HDD to recover whatever files I can.

I ended up with a lot of Word documents (.doc files) that seem to be corrupted. When I open them, I get the following window:

[image]

Is there some way I can scan the directory of Word documents so I end up with only the valid (non-corrupted) Word documents? This will save me from opening and checking each document individually.

**UPDATE:**

The first 32 bytes of data in each of these .doc files was the same ...

```
D0 CF 11 E0 A1 B1 1A E1 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 3E 00 03 00 FE FF 09 00
```

The file signature, `D0 CF 11 E0 A1 B1 1A E1`, tells me that these are Microsoft Office documents. I tried to open one of the files with the following extensions: DOC, DOT, PPS, PPT, XLA, XLS, WIZ. In every case, an error was produced.

Comment: Try running a [TrIDNet](http://mark0.net/soft-tridnet-e.html) scan on the files first to see if they really are Word documents.

Comment: I downloaded the CLI version of the app (so I could use the wildcard * with the -ae switch). It did not re-name any of the word documents. The program wasn't really useful for me in this case, but it may come in handy in the future - thanks!

Comment: Make sure you downloaded the current definitions for TrID as well. It won't work without the [definitions file](http://goo.gl/Bnw1) placed in the same directory as `trid.exe`. Ignore this comment if you've already done that.

Comment: I've already done that. I also just downloaded Remo Repair Word and it tells me the documents are invalid. What I really need is a tool that will look at all my .doc files and tell me which ones are valid and which ones I can toss. Otherwise I will be spending hours opening each file (and most of the files will show an error like above).

Comment: http://www.remosoftware.com/remo-recover-windows-basic

Comment: Could you take a look at about 5 random files with a [hex editor](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) and edit your question with the first 32 bytes of each of those 5 documents?

Comment: Updated question!

Comment: I think I might have a solution for this. Could you upload a sample corrupted file and provide the download link for it?

Comment: Here is a link to one of the files: http://www.filedropper.com/f0676184

Comment: Alright, you can use [Antiword](http://www.winfield.demon.nl/) to try and parse `DOC` files. The Windows version is [available here](http://www-stud.rbi.informatik.uni-frankfurt.de/~markus/antiword/). Unzip files to `C:\antiword`, copy the `DOC` files to that folder and use the command `antiword *.doc > tmp.txt`. Afterwards open `tmp.txt` and if any of those DOC files were valid, you'll see plaintext content of the document and can sort the corrupt files from the rest.

Comment: Using Antiword helped! Can you add that as an answer. I was able to locate all my valid documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Antiword](http://www.winfield.demon.nl/) to try and read `DOC` files. You can get the Windows version [from here](http://www-stud.rbi.informatik.uni-frankfurt.de/~markus/antiword/).

Unzip Antiword to `C:\antiword\` and navigate to that folder using the command prompt.
You may then use the command:

```
antiword PATH_TO_DOC_FILES\*.doc > tmpfile.txt
```

Antiword will output the plain text content of the `DOC` files it was able to read to `tmpfile.txt` and you can then sort the ones that you need and delete the corrupted files.

The output from Antiword might look something like this:

```
::::::::::::::
Document 1.doc
::::::::::::::
                                Sample Document 1

This is a sample Word document.

::::::::::::::
Document 2.doc
::::::::::::::
                                Sample Document 2

This is another sample Word document.

::::::::::::::
Corrupt Document.doc
::::::::::::::

::::::::::::::
Another Corrupt Document.doc
::::::::::::::
```

You could then maybe use `grep` or do some regular expression matching to find the names of the corrupt documents and delete them.